# CakePHP conditional query with controller that 'hasAndBelongsToMany'

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I apologize for the horrible title, I couldn't think of how to explain my problem.

In my database I have the following tables, `articles`, `tags`, and `articles_tags`. An article can have many tags.

Currently I am able to grab all the articles, with all the tags, but I want to be able to find articles based upon it's tags.

My select is simple:

```
$articles = $this->Article->find('all', array(
    // extra condition to check for tag, maybe?
    'conditions'    => array('Article.status' => 'active'), 
    'limit'         => $this->articles_per_page,
    'offset'        => ($page_num-1)*$this->articles_per_page
));
```

My return from the database is as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Article] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
            )

        [Tag] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => Ruby
                        [slug] => ruby
                        [uses] => 1
                        [ArticlesTag] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [article_id] => 1
                                [tag_id] => 1
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

What do I do if I only want to return the articles with a `Ruby` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
// In your Article model
function getArticleByTagSql($tag)
{       
        $dbo = $this->getDataSource();
        $subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
        array(
                    'fields' => array('DISTINCT(ArticlesTag.article_id)'),
                    'table' => "articles_tags",                                    
                    'joins' => array(
                                array('table' => 'tags',
                                    'alias' => 'Tag',
                                    'type' => 'INNER',
                                    'conditions' => array('ArticlesTag.tag_id = Tag.id')
                                    )
                                ),
                    'alias'=>"ArticlesTag",                                         
                    'conditions' => array("Tag.name"=>Sanitize::clean($tag_words)),
                    'order' => null,
                    'group' => "ArticlesTag.article_id"
                    ),
                    $this
                    );
                    $subQuery = ' Article.id  IN (' . $subQuery . ')';
                    return $dbo->expression($subQuery);

}

// In your Articles Controller

$this->paginate['conditions'][] = $this->Article->getArticleByTagSql($tag_name);
$this->paginate['conditions'][] = array('Article.status' => 'active');
$this->paginate['limit'] = $this->articles_per_page;



// or as per your example
$articles = $this->Article->find('all', array(
                // extra condition to check for tag, maybe?
                'conditions'    => array('Article.status' => 'active',$this->Article->getArticleByTagSql($tag_name)), 
                'limit'         => $this->articles_per_page,
                'offset'        => ($page_num-1)*$this->articles_per_page
            ));
```

Answer (score 2):

For conditions like this you can use the [LinkableBehavior](https://github.com/Terr/Linkable). It's designed for exact your wanted result. In case you don't want to use it, you have to do a query on the tag controller:

```
$this->Tag->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Tag.name' => 'ruby')));
```

Comment: re the comment you left on my answer.  I've used something similar with pagination. But I can't verify because I don't access to my cake machine. I'll have a look when I get home, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: if I preform the query from the tags controller, I run into almost the same problem. This is because the articles have a status field and I need to check if the status is active.

Comment: @Paramount, so Leo's solution is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Not possible directly.

The easiest way is to make the query through the tag controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating this question with an answer for CakePHP 3.x.

You can find all `articles` for a given `tag` using an INNER JOIN. The benefit of this join is that it keeps *articles* as the primary table in the query. Making this an easy solution when you're paginating results by a HABTM join.

```
$tag_id = 3; // the ID of the tag

$query = $this->Articles->find('all')
                 ->innerJoin('articles_tags', [
                      'Articles.id = articles_tags.article_id',
                      'articles_tags.tag_id' => $tag_id
                 ]);
```

The first join condition has to be the array key. If you use a `=>` array assignment then CakePHP will pass the `articles_tags.article_id` as a *string* argument to the join condition. Which won't work.

You can also stack `innerJoin` for multiple HABTM conditions. For example; find all *articles* for a *tag* and also for a *category*. You can also use the `in` query expression to match multiple *tags*.

You can also use the above in pagination like this `$articles = $this->paginate($query);`

I'm sure this information is out on the web, but this question was the top of google's results. So maybe this will help others.