# CakePHP Getting Associated Posts from Tag

Tags: php, cakephp, controller, find

I've got three tables

- posts
- tags
- posts_tags

I need to write some controller logic that selects and sets all posts that have the tag `work`

This means querying the `tags` to find the `id` for the queried tag, checking in the associated `posts_tags` table to find matches, using the `post_id` to return the correct posts from the posts table.

I'm not sure how to even begin this query, I'm new to CakePHP and could use a hand... Please?

If it helps, here's my posts model relationship:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Tag' => array(
            'className' => 'Tag',
            'joinTable' => 'posts_tags',
            'foreignKey' => 'posts_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

My Tag table is made up of two fields: `id` and `tag`
My PostsTag table is made up of three fields: `id`, `tag_id` and `post_id`
My Posts table is made up of four fields: `id`, `title`, `body` and `created`

I found some code on the CakePHP Book that shows the below code:

```
$this->Recipe->Tag->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Tag.name'=>'Dessert')));
```

They suggested that it was a similar idea, so I attempted to adapt:

```
$this->Post->Tag->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Tag.tag'=>'work')));
```

However, this has not worked. This returns all Posts without filtering.

I took the advice of @Leo and tried to adapt his code to mine:

```
function getArticleByTagSql($tag) {
        $dbo = $this->getDataSource();
        $subQuery = $dbo->buildStatement(
                        array(
                    'fields' => array('DISTINCT(ArticlesTag.article_id)'),
                    'table' => "articles_tags",
                    'joins' => array(
                        array('table' => 'tags',
                            'alias' => 'Tag',
                            'type' => 'INNER',
                            'conditions' => array('ArticlesTag.tag_id = Tag.id')
                        )
                    ),
                    'alias' => "ArticlesTag",
                    'conditions' => array("Tag.tag" => $tag),
                    'order' => null,
                    'group' => "ArticlesTag.article_id",
                    'limit' => null
                        ), 
                $this
        );
        $subQuery = ' Article.id  IN (' . $subQuery . ')';
        return $dbo->expression($subQuery);
    }
```

Controller:

```
$this->set('articles', $this->paginate(array(
            'conditions' => $this->Article->getArticleByTagSql('work')
        )));
```

However, whatever I type in the paginate() method as a key - in this case 'conditions' appears in the query and I can't figure out why - I keep getting unknown column 'conditions' errors. The error is with the paginate function, the data returns correctly without it, but I cannot use the paginator without it. It's like a catch 22

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Can you post what are the field names in your tag table?

Comment: @Headshota - I've updated my question to include them.

Comment: Daniel you are using paginate incorrectly, you do not declare 'conditions' in the paginate call.

Set $this->paginate['conditions'] = $this->Article->getArticleByTagSql('work');

Then call $this->paginate('Article');

Comment: Sorry using Post instead of Article!

Comment: @Leo, the query generates an unusual array layout and paginate counts were failing, so I followed the 'advanced pagination' page on the cake book and I'm good. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel this question is actually answered in the [Cake documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) when describing the HABTM relationship betweens Receipe/Tag

I [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986507/cakephp-conditional-query-with-controller-that-hasandbelongstomany/5990310#5990310) for someone who had a similar issue with an Article/Tag models, that answer used a subquery

Comment: I get an SQL error with this: `$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM 'articles' AS 'Article'   WHERE 'conditions' =  Article.id  IN (SELECT DISTINCT(ArticlesTag.article_id) FROM articles_tags AS 'ArticlesTag' INNER JOIN tags AS 'Tag' ON ('ArticlesTag'.'tag_id' = 'Tag'.'id')  WHERE 'Tag'.'tag' = 'work'  GROUP BY 'ArticlesTag'.'article_id'  )   "
$error = "1054: Unknown column 'conditions' in 'where clause'"
$out = null`

Comment: You led me onto some interesting ground. Ultimately I solved the paging problem by overriding the pagingCount method. It now works fine. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

if you use:

```
$this->Post->Tag->find('all'...
```

you're telling him to find all Tags work... and since its recursive, each tag will contain the related posts..

try doing this instead:

```
$this->Post->find('all'...
```

hopefully cake will be smart enough (and if you have correctly set your models relations) to only select posts that have the "work" tag.. and if that doesnt work, you could always set the joins "manually" using a [complex find condition](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions)

Good Luck

Comment: hmmm now that i think about it.. this might not work :P.. if it doesnt, please provide the generated query =)

Comment: thanks mate, I'll have a go. I'll have to do it when I get home from work tonight so, if your in the UK end of the map, expect an answer around 8 or 9 ish ;) Cheers for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, but I tried this query and it worked for me...May be it will work for you too :)

```
$claims = $this->Claim->query("SELECT DISTINCT Claim.id,Claim.title, Claim.description FROM
             claims as Claim
             LEFT JOIN claim_tags as ClaimTag ON Claim.id = ClaimTag.claim_id
            LEFT JOIN tags as Tag ON Tag.id =ClaimTag.tag_id
            WHERE Tag.id = '$id'");
```