# CakePHP GROUP BY with WHERE and COUNT on HATBM table

Tags: cakephp, count, group-by, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.2

Although I'm aware of the `group`, `contain`, `fields` and `order` options on a `find()`, I just cannot seem to make the following query with CakePHP 2.2.3 :

```
SELECT `User`.*, SUM(`Influence`.`id`) AS matches
FROM `db`.`users` AS `User` 
    LEFT JOIN `db`.`influences_users` AS `InfluencesUser` ON (`User`.`id` = `InfluencesUser`.`user_id`) 
    LEFT JOIN `db`.`influences` AS `Influence` ON (`InfluencesUser`.`influence_id` = `Influence`.`id`)
WHERE 1 = 1
AND `Influence`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY `User`.`id` 
ORDER BY COUNT(`Influence`.`id`) DESC
```

Basically, I'm trying to retrieve an array of `Users` having the `Influences` 1, 2, 3 and 4, with the `COUNT()` function on the `Influences` tables, then order them by `COUNT() DESC`.

Is there a clean way (I'd rather not want to use any hacks or functions like `Model::query()`) to do so in CakePHP?

**EDIT:** *It wasn't actually a `SUM()` but rather a `COUNT()` although I doesn't change anything to my problem.*

Comment: try using virtual fields here - makes the query way more readable and usable afterwards.

Comment: @mark I thought of it, but how? Aren't virtual fields meant to be used for data within the current model? And I only need this `SUM()` field in this particular function. If I find a way to use the virtual field for that, wouldn't it make the model heavier but adding this field everytime I'll be using the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, not too hacky and unless someone has a better solution (not a lot when you see the number of answers I got), here it is:

```
$this->User->virtualFields['matches'] = 'COUNT(InfluencesUser.influence_id)';
$matches = $this->User->find(
        'all',
        array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'alias' => 'InfluencesUser',
                    'table' => 'influences_users',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'InfluencesUser.influence_id' => $userInfluences, //$userInfluences contains the list of influences I want to do the restriction on
                        '`InfluencesUser`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'group' => 'User.id',
            'order' => array('User__matches' => 'DESC'),
        ));
```

I manually join the `InfluencesUser` table (I don't actually need the `Influence` one, only the list of `influence_id`) to make a big table. I just had to do the restriction (`influence_id`) on the `join` table, then I can do my `goup by`, the `count()` and append the `count()` field to my results array, thanks to [mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564486/cakephp-group-by-with-where-and-count-on-hatbm-table/13565764#13565764).

Obviously I would have prefered using something like the `contain` parameter, but it doesn't seem to allow me to do what I can achieve with the `join` in this particular situation.

Hope this could save some time to some people.

Answer (score 5):

you can add virtual fields dynamically for only the next queries using

```
$this->virtualFields['matches'] = 'SUM(Influence.id)';
```

then you have it directly in your result array to work with:

```
echo $user['User']['matches']; // if you query on the User model that is
```

also you can use it on your order/conditions etc:

```
'order' => array('User__matches' => 'DESC')
```

You need to work on the model, that has all the other models as "belongsTo", though!
So work with "InfluencesUser" and contain "Influence" and "User"

So in your case:

```
$this->User->InfluencesUser->virtualFields['matches'] = 'SUM(Influence.id)';
...
$results = $this->User->InfluencesUser->find(...)
```

and

```
echo $result['InfluencesUser']['matches']; //in the view
```

and

```
'order' => array('InfluencesUser__matches' => 'DESC')
```

Comment: I didn't know about doing it on the fly; It's thowing an error unless I add the model name, like `$this->User->virtualFields...`. Although this is pretty cool, it still not actually answering my question (unless I did not quite fully understand your answer).

Comment: you cannot make a single query in hasMany directions. you need to query the hasMany model and contain the belongsTo models. this way you can achieve the above. my answer was just about using the cleaner virtualFields approach here in general.

Answer (score 0):

how about a sub query?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5990310/190669) using this approach for a HATBM issue. It is a useful approach for complex queries.

Comment: So how would you do in this particular situation?